# Notifications of software updates in Ubuntu 22.04 show up later in the Software app than they do in the terminal

Tags: updates, 22.04, gnome-software

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and kernel Linux 5.19.0-38-generic kernel. Why do I get different software updates from Software & Updates app v. 0.99.22.6 than I get from GNOME Software app v. 41.5, and additionally from time to time I get upgradable apps information from the terminal using `apt list --upgradable` or `apt-get upgradable` which is also different from the information that I get from GNOME Software?

Comment: Sorry this question does not make sense and there is no info here to be able to offer any help.

Comment: @David It does make sense because when you run `sudo apt update` from the terminal it forces apt to check for updates immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome Software checks for updates at different time intervals than Software Updater does, so the Software Updater may notify the user of updates that the Software app still does not know about. Similarly running `sudo apt update` from the terminal may notify the user of updates that the Software app still does not know about, because  `sudo apt update` forces apt to check for updates immediately.

For snap packages the situation is somewhat different in that notifications of pending updates to snap packages sometimes appear in the Panel of the desktop next to the clock. Running `sudo snap refresh` from the terminal will install all pending updates to snap packages.